# How to contact cell when you press Button different cell

Tags: swift, cell

I have a collection view and I have two different cells I need when opening the application opens cell and when you press button  opens another cell thanks for help

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TOWCell", for: indexPath) as! TOWCell
        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UPCOMINGViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UPCOMINGViewCell
        return cell
    }
}


@IBAction func differentcellsButon(_ sender: Any) {
    /// here I need call cells
}
```

Comment: What do you mean button opens another cell? you mean it adds a cell to the collectionView?

Comment: Use concept of Sections and cells , when user click on section add cells in that respective section

Comment: Try using a global variable say var isFristCell = true and use that inside cell cellForItemAt method, if isFristCell == true return first cell else return second cell, and inside  differentcellsButon change value of  isFristCell to false and reload the collection view

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@IBAction func differentcellsButon(_ sender: Any) {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code**

```
//Declare this line on top of your ViewController
 var isFirstCell = true


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if isFirstCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TOWCell", for: indexPath) as! TOWCell
            return cell
        }else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UPCOMINGViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UPCOMINGViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }


    @IBAction func differentcellsButon(_ sender: Any) {
        /// here I need call cells
        self.isFirstCell = false
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: hello I have Error  its problems

Comment: The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-04-20 03:28:48.194251-0700 TwoLive[3681:165300] -[TwoLive.MainVC UpcomingButon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa27b60c030
2018-04-20 03:28:48.260502-0700 TwoLive[3681:165300] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TwoLive.MainVC UpcomingButon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa27b60c030'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Please provide your complete project or class so that i can fix that is that possible !